# I moved a VM with snapshots and I now cant recover from snapshot

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, snapshot

I moved a Virtual Machine and it's files to another pc (moved, not cloned), and now I can't recover from snapshots.

I have all the files (of the VM) but no snapshots shown in the program.

I need to recover from the latest snapshot, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have snapshot files, even if not displayed in the gui, open a terminal and hit the following on command line

```
VBoxManage snapshot <path/to/'including space'/VMname.vbox> list
```

This return a list of snapshot available for the VM. The following will restore the VM to a snapshot.

```
VBoxManage snapshot <path/to/'including space'/VMname.vbox> restore <SnapshotName>
```

Remember to work while the VM is not running.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I cant make it work. My path to VM its named: "F:\VDIs\DAW Emilio", what can I do with that space to make command line work? I did try with %20 and with "<F:\VDIs\DAW Emilio>". I did use "/" insted of "\". Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you put quotes around the path? (`"` or `'`, not `<` or `>`)

Comment: I did hit "VBoxManage snapshot F:\VDIs\'DAW Emilio'\DAW Emilio.vbox list" and console displays: "Could not find a registered machine named 'F:\VDIs\'DAW'", so the space isnt working

Comment: @CHR see last edit about drag and drop of the paths

Comment: I cant drag and drop, It likes selects where I click insted of dragging it. What I did now its: VBoxManage snapshot "F:\VDIs\DAW Emilio\DAW Emilio.vbox" list ; and the cmd says: Could not find a registered machine named 'F:\VDIs\DAW Emilio\DAW Emilio.vbox'

Comment: I did change computer, I moved the files with a portable HDD to another pc btw

Comment: ok so: close terminal; browse to the vbox file with file explorer; hit cmd in the bar. You are now in the directory of the vbox file. Hit the following `VBoxManage snapshot "DAW Emilio.vbox" list` (if the vbox file name is `DAW Emilio.vbox` )

Comment: @CHR please explain the current situation

Comment: my problem is that i have to be in oracle/virtualbox in order to use VBoxManage, so i dont know what to do

Comment: Okay, I did this:

F:\VDIs\DAW Emilio>"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VboxManage" snapshot "DAW Emilio.vbox" list


VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'DAW Emilio.vbox'


VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown


VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(bstrMachine.raw(), pMachine.asOutParam())" at line 326 of file VBoxManageSnapshot.cpp

Comment: drag and drop the vbox file from file manager to the terminal

Comment: @CHR anycase the point moved from the original question to the path issue. I suggest to create another question focusing the point on the path issue (i have a virtual machine here ....... i run this command ...... i get this error ....... ) with screenshot too. Better do this before some big user wipe out all this mess. After that, you will see the command i provided here are correct and mark this question answered. I'll follow up your new question too